# Accessing a Visual Studio 2010 Web Server over a local network

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis-express

I am looking to be able to accept incoming requests to my debug web servers environment from elsewhere on my local network.

For example:

Development Box: Local IIS Express Web server(deployed through Visual Studio "Use Local IIS Web Server" check box) is running on "localhost:9005/push" (My current IP is 10.100.7.61)

I'm attempting to connect from 10.100.7.60 using the URL "10.100.7.61:9005/push"

I know that the Visual Studio Development Server is not accessible from the local network, but I don't see why the IIS Express Server would not be?

I have been able to access the URL from my Local IIS(Not through the Visual Studio Deployment Server) by deploying the website to the IIS instance (running on port 9004) so I know that I am able to get at my box.

I know that Visual Studio's internal Web Server is not accessible from outside of your computer, but I assumed that the Local IIS Web Server was the work around to this.

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks, 
Matthew

Answer (score 0):

You should bind the ip address of your iis express server as below:

```
 <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:9005:10.100.7.61" />
```

The configuration file should be located under sites/site/bindings

Hope this helps.